# What is giant blue target in SC2 Legacy of the Void?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Just started playing Into the Void. Warming up against computers. I noticed a blue target in a wide area around my units while I played against Terran. I'm thinking it's the Liberator but I recall using that unit and it's defender mode sat there and attacked units one at a time. Not sure what ability I was seeing.

Comment: do you have a screenshot?

Comment: I'll need to bag it next time, but I figure there's not too many Terran units that would give an indicator. I mean I know the Raven's seeker just makes your unit red.

Comment: I know of several red indicators, but not blue ones, are you sure it wasn't from one of your units? what race were you playing? blue is generally more used for yourself or allies while red is for the enemy

Comment: Do you mean "Into the Void" campaign mission, the first in the Epilogue?

Comment: @orcJMR considering OP has originally written "into the void" in the title I assume they also meant of the void in the first sentence

Comment: @DaveStein is [this what you're talking about?](http://i.imgur.com/IUD5meg.png) This is from the liberator, was the enemy's colour blue by any chance? I believe it changes colour with the players colour

Comment: @Aequitas man sorry I disappeared! You are correct with your comment. You should make it an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct it is the Liberator's attack circle while in defender mode. [See here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhfCJ.png).

The colour is the same as the player's colour, that's why in my image it is green. In your case your opponent must've been blue and thus the attack circle is also blue.